# How to solve a nonlinear overdetermined system of equations

Tags: equation-solving, nonlinear

i'm trying to solve a nonlinear overdetermined system of equations (124 equations, 123 variables) i tried this procedure (newton raphson)

`NewtonExtended[f_List, x_List, x0_List, eps_: 10^-12, n_: 100] := 
 With[{jac = N[Outer[D, f, x]]}, 
  FixedPoint[(# + 
      PseudoInverse[
        jac /. Thread[x -> N[#]]].(-f /. Thread[x -> N[#]])) &, N[x0],
    n, SameTest -> (Sqrt[Abs[(#1 - #2).(#1 - #2)]] < eps &)]]`

but it takes so long (without giving any solution) because i'm using a signal of 300 samples (need to use it 300 times), i need a procedure to be quick and gives the solution in a reasonable time

Comment: Why not reformulate as an optimization problem that you can give to `FindMinimum[]`/`NMinimize[]`?

Comment: @Guesswhoitis. i don't know how to use it properly

Comment: Treat each equation as a component in the sum of squares that you'll be minimizing.